# Random stop jobs on shutdown/bootup

Tags: 15.10

I've been noticing that practically **every** time I bootup Ubuntu or shut it down, this job appears:
`A stop job is running for: LSB: Privilege escalation detection system [0s / 30s]`
It's been annoying me because it makes me wait at least 30 seconds to start up or shut down my computer.
So, my question is: **what is this, and how can I get rid of it?**

**If it helps, here is the output of `systemctl list-units | grep -i Privilege`:**

```
username@hostname:~$ systemctl list-units | grep -i Privilege
ninja.service                                                                loaded active running   LSB: "privilege escalation detection system"
polkitd.service                                                              loaded active running   Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks
username@hostname:~$
```

Comment: Do something like `grep -r escalation /lib/systemd/*` to find out which service is described as "Privilege escalation system" (I couldn't find one), then see if you can (and should) remove it from your system.

Comment: I have the same list as you (binary matches only), except that I don't have `systemd-resolve-host`.

Comment: Try `systemctl list-units | grep -i Privilege` (or `systemctl list-units | grep LSB` etc.)

Comment: Well, there's your problem. Do `sudo apt remove ninja`. That is your privilege escalation detection service.

Comment: @Jos Will it have any side effects?

Comment: Try it, and see what else gets removed. You can always press 'n' to cancel.

Comment: @Jos just ninja